# How do I show the HTML descrption in wordpress photo gallery for my individual gallery pages?

Tags: plugin-development, html, gallery

Using the wordpress gallery below, I want to show the html content of an anchor tag so that when I click on a link to get to a specific gallery I will navigate to the anchor tag in the description section.

https://10web.io/plugins/wordpress-photo-gallery/

Enable HTML editor is clearly selected
[image]

HTML Tag is Visible
[image]

But my HTML does not appear in the gallery specific page for one of my galleries.  Nor do I see any description section.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

With some CSS/HTML I managed to solve my issue.  But,  I had to enable Gallery title right above the description setting checkbox in my screenshot.

HTML

```
<a href="/bwg_gallery/<slug-url-here>/#top" name="top"></a>
<h4>Title</h4>
```

Addtional CSS ( to hide the title since I already have a title above this one )

```
.bwg_gal_title_0:not(.bwg_gal_description_0){
    display: none !important;
}
```